# XSLT Transformation to retain xml nodes

Tags: xslt

```html
<Batches>
    <UploadInfo>   
        <UploadSAPInfo>          
          <BATCHID>100</BATCHID>
          <SerialNo>20141</SerialNo>
          <STATUS>P</STATUS>          
        </UploadSAPInfo>
        <UploadSAPInfo>          
          <BATCHID>100</BATCHID>
          <SerialNo>20142</SerialNo>
          <STATUS>P</STATUS>          
        </UploadSAPInfo>
    </UploadInfo>

   <UploadInfo>   
        <UploadSAPInfo>          
          <BATCHID>200</BATCHID>
          <SerialNo>20151</SerialNo>
          <STATUS>F</STATUS>          
        </UploadSAPInfo>
        <UploadSAPInfo>          
          <BATCHID>200</BATCHID>
          <SerialNo>20142</SerialNo>
          <STATUS>P</STATUS>          
        </UploadSAPInfo>
    </UploadInfo>
</Batches>
```

This is my xml structure, I need to change BATCHID like ('B001','B002'..)for each uploadInfo and to retain the other nodes as its is using xslt.

The XSLT which I used

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
>

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="BATCHID">
   <xsl:text>B001</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="UploadBatchTemplate" match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="UploadBatchInfo">
        <xsl:call-template name="BATCHID"></xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- end snippet -->
```

I don't know how to pass the entire node to the call-template. The BATCHID is replaced in all the nodes.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What do you need to change BATCHID to? Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I like to change BATCHID to "B001" , "B002" ... like this.

Comment: Try using an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying), add a template to override `BATCHID`, generate the new value based on `uploadInfo` (maybe `xsl:number`...`<xsl:number count="UploadInfo" format="000"/>` for the numeric portion) and then come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have any problems.

Comment: I would also suggest adding a small example of the output XML you desire - an example is much easier to work with than a vague description. In XML transform questions it is ideal to have the starting XML, an example of desired output XML and any XSLT you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way, perhaps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BATCHID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text>B</xsl:text>
        <xsl:number from="UploadInfo" level="any" format="001"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batches>
   <UploadInfo>
      <UploadSAPInfo>
         <BATCHID>B001</BATCHID>
         <SerialNo>20141</SerialNo>
         <STATUS>P</STATUS>
      </UploadSAPInfo>
      <UploadSAPInfo>
         <BATCHID>B002</BATCHID>
         <SerialNo>20142</SerialNo>
         <STATUS>P</STATUS>
      </UploadSAPInfo>
   </UploadInfo>
   <UploadInfo>
      <UploadSAPInfo>
         <BATCHID>B001</BATCHID>
         <SerialNo>20151</SerialNo>
         <STATUS>F</STATUS>
      </UploadSAPInfo>
      <UploadSAPInfo>
         <BATCHID>B002</BATCHID>
         <SerialNo>20142</SerialNo>
         <STATUS>P</STATUS>
      </UploadSAPInfo>
   </UploadInfo>
</Batches>
```

Comment: @ravi-shankar - If you read my comment and then look at this answer, this is exactly what I was suggesting. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet allows you to clone every node in the input XML (but it does not process attributes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to process certain nodes specificly, it's enough to add an specific template:

```
<xsl:template match="BATCHID">
    <BATCHID>B<xsl:value-of select="."/></BATCHID>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This does not "clone" every node. Aside from not handling attributes, like you said, it doesn't handle comments or processing instructions and more importantly, removes the element nodes from any namespace they might be in.